# Why doesn't Stackoverflow use Ajax for the edit feature?

Tags: ajax

Why doesn't Stack Overflow use Ajax for the "edit question" feature?

It would be better for the user i think right? It would load faster. Plus they would use less bandwidth.

Are there any downsides for doing it?

My only guess is, that it's more work, because you have to sync the client and the server data.

Comment: Debugging is the same in MVC and WebAPI.  I'm not really sure what kind of answers you're looking for here, other than whether anyone here personally likes or dislikes WebAPI as a framework.

Comment: How is it not the same?  Client-side debugging can be done in a browser, server-side in Visual Studio.  (Some client-side debugging can be done in Visual Studio too, the tooling has improved over the years.  But personally I prefer the browser tools for that.)  What's different?  It's really not clear what you're even asking here, and I wonder if that comes from some misunderstandings you might have about what MVC and WebAPI are and how they work.

Comment: I think you may have some confusion about the WebAPI framework.  It doesn't have a UX.  It's entirely server-side and is simply a framework for creating an API for other software to consume.  As for why any given website does or does not use it, I guess you'd have to ask the makers of that website.  (Though unless the website indicates somehow that it uses it, there's no way to know just from client-side interaction.)

Comment: Are you talking about *AJAX* rather than WebAPI?  The two are very different things.

Comment: At this point I'm really confused about the premise of your question.  First, if you're asking about AJAX, then focus on AJAX.  WebAPI really has nothing to do with that.  Second, what "big sites" *don't* use AJAX?

Comment: @David i re-wrote my question completely now. Is this the correct way of doing it or should i start a new question and close this one?

Comment: *"Why doesn't Stackoverflow use Ajax for the edit feature"* it does doesn't it? I see an XHR entry in my network tab to edit-submit with the form data, and a json response.

Comment: @KevinB you see this when you click on the "edit" question link?

Comment: When i click edit all it does is change to an edit box, it doesn't reload the page or send any ajax.

Comment: eh, take that back, it does send an ajax request, i had wrong dev window open. but it is not reloading the page.

Comment: @KevinB hmm... When i click on the edit question html link no ajax is executed (firefox developer tools -> network). Maybe you clicked on the edit comment link?

Comment: Nope, it was definitely edit post. using chrome 47.

Comment: This is a question for the meta site

Comment: @KevinB The only XHR entry which i get in chrome is the one for title validation. Nothing else. :/